# How to restore DNS settings in fedora

Tags: fedora, dns, networkmanager

I recently added a Wi-Fi network, where I manually set it including DNS, but when I get to my home Wi-Fi network, I realize that some applications like Discord don't work, it stays in an infinite cycle looking for updates or a Java project , where it connects to MongoDB and throws a connection error, which according to the internet is a DNS problem

In my `/etc/resolv.conf` file I have the following:

```
nameserver 200.72.1.5
nameserver 200.72.1.11
```

Which are the DNS that you use to adjust the Wifi network manually and that I think are conflicting

Try adjusting the DNS automatically or using the NetworkManager where you use the following values in the `NetworkManager.conf` file:

```
[Main]
dns=200.28.4.129,200.28.4.130
```

According to the Wifi settings of Fedora, the DNS have been changed but the problem persists, I'm sure it's related to this, since before these applications worked perfectly for me, it is worth mentioning that the resolve.conf file is unwritable

How can I restore to factory settings or make the resolve.conf file blank?

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the network interface when making the DNS change?

The `resolv.conf` take the config from the start, so, i think you need to restart the NetworkManager, to take the new config for the DNS.

Try this.

```
systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: `resolv.conf` is more or less "live", As soon as you change it, new processes use the new value. What you *might* have to do, is restart the process not working.